# Java HTTP Proxy. When to close sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, http, proxy

I'm writing a rather simple HTTP Proxy in Java for a University Project (thus I'm only allowed to use the built-in JDK functionality).

I'm quite confused about persistent connections while writing my software.
The proxy should be able to parse/manipulate all the http messages so I need to collect everything and can't just forward it.

Here's how I do the basic things in principle:
One thread is listening for connections from the browser. When a connection appears, I start a thread. It reads from the stream (client -> proxy) and forwards it on (proxy -> server).

Now I have heard that a browser may use the same connection to the proxy for different hosts so it is possible that there is 1 thread for client->proxy communication and multiple  child threads which forward to different hosts.

My proxy works already in some cases. But I have issues with threads not getting killed.

When do I actually have to close my Java socket streams for the different connections?

**Right now I do for the different streams:**

- client->proxy: do nothing
- proxy->1 server: close when proxy reads -1    from client
- 1 server -> proxy: nothing
- proxy -> client: close when    ALL (server->client) threads read -1. (so when every server has    closed its connection to the proxy).

But that doesn't quit get it right and I have a hard time debugging.

Is this in principle correct?

And to add: Do I have to take care of proxy-connection:keep-alive and Connection:close headers or can I just forward them? Because at the moment I don't do anything related to them, but I have a feeling that this is the main issue, I just want to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

A proxy can be considered both a server and a client, and the connections on the two sides are largely independent, and they should be managed separately.

```
        conn                   conn
client----------server-client---------server
                -------------
                   proxy
```

A client-proxy connection is used to carry multiple requests (possibly to different servers).

A proxy-server connection is used to carry multiple requests (possible from different clients)

***`Connection` header is hop-by-hop; it should not be forwarded***. How connections are created/terminated is between client-proxy, or proxy-server, but not between client-server.

Answer (score -1):

> When do I actually have to close my Java socket streams for the different connections?

1. When read returns -1 on a socket, shutdown the opposite socket for output.
2. If you had already shutdown the socket you read EOS from, close them both.
3. You don't have to do anything about the Connection: keepalive and Connection:close headers: just forward them and let the endpoints decide. All you have to do is react to, and propagate, end of stream correctly.

This is the correct way to propagate FINs transparently. It doesn't make any difference to the above whether the stream is upstream or downstream.